# LINQ join: Flexibility on list of structs

Tags: c#, list, linq, variables, struct

apologises if the question is dumb, by I've want to know something to simplify my code:

I have a few lists:

```
public struct structure
{
     public string item1;
     public string item2;
     public string item3;
     public string item4;
}
public List <structure> listOfStruct=new List <structure>();
public List <string> lista;
public List <string> listb;
```

With below code I use the LINQ join to find matches in both lists:

```
                    query = from x in listOfStruct
                        join y2 in lista on x.item1 equals y2
                        select new
                        {
                            x.action
                        };

                        foreach (var item in query)
                        { 
                            Answer = item.answer;
                        }
```

The variable 'Answer' then is used for further processing.

The thing is that somewhere else in my code I need to match another list with listOfStruct, but with another item of the struct:

```
                    query = from x in listOfStruct
                        join y2 in listB on x.item2 equals y2
                        select new
                        {
                            x.action
                        };


                        foreach (var item in query)
                        { 
                            Answer = item.answer;
                        }
```

I would like to write a function something like this

```
public string matchList(string actionListItem, string [] second_list){
                       query = from x in listOfStruct
                            join y2 in second_list on x.actionListItem equals y2
                            select new
                            {
                                x.action
                            };

                            foreach (var item in query)
                            { 
                                Answer = item.answer;
                            }
                            return Answer;
}
```

and call if from anywhere in my program with something like below to be flexible and not write the same piece of code over and over again:

```
var action= matchList(string itemInlistOfStruct,string []secondList)
```

where "itemInListOfStruct" could be item1, item2...or item4 and "seconList" lista or listb.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd like to help, but as you've only written pseudo-code, it's very hard to tell what you're actually trying to do with the query. (Your method uses `x` as if it's a regular variable when it's only a range variable, and doesn't do anything with `query`.) It would also help to make your question more legible if you'd follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Hi John, I've editted the code somewhat. var query is the result of the join. This value is then assigned to the variable "Answer" which I use for further processing

Comment: Except `Answer` is never declared anywhere, and you're only returning the last element of the query, which seems pretty odd. If you'd provide a [mcve] it would be much easier to help you. (Additionally, please pay more attention to formatting the code - why is it indented so far over to the right?)

Answer (score 0):

You must define the comparison with Strings for your structure. Use the following procedure to do this

```
public struct structure
{
     public string item1;
     public string item2;
     public string item3;
     public string item4;

     public override bool Equals(string obj) 
     {

      return obj==item1;//your code for check Equals
     }

}
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do with matching elements of `listOfStruct` (which indeed is very unclear in your question), filtering out those matches is independent from processing them consecutively. So I'd suggest to split the matching and the further processing into two simpler steps.

I'd prefer to use a class instead of a struct in this case, so i rename your struct`structure` into the class `Thing`, also changing the type of `Item2` for demonstration purposes:

```
public sealed class Thing
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public int Item2 { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Now make some extension methods as you need:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> MatchBy<TSource, TItem>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TItem> keySelector, IEnumerable<TItem> keys)
    {
        var keySet = keys as ISet<TItem> ?? new HashSet<TItem>(keys);
        return source.Where(x => keySet.Contains(keySelector(x)));
        // or equivalently, if you prefer
        // return from x in source where keySet.Contains(keySelector(x)) select x;
    }

    public static string FurtherProcessing(this IEnumerable<Thing> things) => $"Number of things: {things.Count()}.";
}
```

And use them like this:

```
    var things = new List<Thing>
    {
        new Thing { Item1 = "Foo", Item2 = 0 },
        new Thing { Item1 = "Bar", Item2 = 1 },
        new Thing { Item1 = "Bla", Item2 = 2 },
    };
    var answerByItem1 = things.MatchBy(thing => thing.Item1, new[] { "Foo", "Bar" }).FurtherProcessing();
    var answerByItem2 = things.MatchBy(thing => thing.Item2, new[] { 1 }).FurtherProcessing();
```

If all of your `ItemXXX` are strings and you really need to identify them by name, you can add another overload of MatchBy:

```
public static IEnumerable<Thing> MatchBy(this IEnumerable<Thing> source, string keyName, IEnumerable<string> keys)
{
    switch (keyName)
    {
        case nameof(Thing.Item1): return source.MatchBy(x => x.Item1, keys);
        // case ...
        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(keyName));
    }
}
```